# How to set up Swagger with express?

Tags: coffeescript, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using the [{swagger-express}](https://github.com/fliptoo/swagger-express) library and my code is all in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). For my definition, I have:

```
app.use swagger.init app,
  apis: ['./src/routes.coffee', './src/models.yml']
  apiVersion: '0.1.0'
  basePath: "http://localhost:#{port}"
  info:
    title: 'My API'
    description: 'A complete listing of all API functions'
  swaggerUI: path.join __dirname, 'public'
  swaggerURL: '/swagger'

require('./src/routes') app
```

In `routes`, I have:

```
  ###
   * @swagger
   * path: /login
   * operations:
   *   -  httpMethod: POST
   *      summary: Login with username and password
   *      notes: Returns a user based on username
   *      responseClass: User
   *      nickname: login
   *      consumes:
   *        - text/html
   *      parameters:
   *        - name: username
   *          description: Your username
   *          paramType: query
   *          required: true
   *          dataType: string
   *        - name: password
   *          description: Your password
   *          paramType: query
   *          required: true
   *          dataType: string
  ###
```

and that works fine. My `model.yml` file is:

```
definitions:
  User:
    properties:
      user_id:
        type: string
        description: Unique ID to represent the user
      first_name:
        type: string
        description: First name of the Uber user.
      last_name:
        type: string
        description: Last name of the Uber user.
      email:
        type: string
        description: Email address of the Uber user
      picture:
        type: string
        description: Image URL of the Uber user.
      promo_code:
        type: string
        description: Promo code of the Uber user.
```

But that doesn't show up in the `api-docs.json`. I am trying to define the `models` in one file and the `paths` in another. Can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it will work because each format is read separately and saved in a hash which is uses the `resourcePath` as the key.

https://github.com/fliptoo/swagger-express/blob/a5560af936e5398affe36d347af5be2a1bb64fc2/lib/swagger-express/index.js#L27

Any further declaration of the same `resourcePath` will override the previous declaration.

I tested with an updated yml format with a `resourcePath`, the name `models` instead of `definitions` and a unique `id` for the model. This made the models show up but none of my other information :/

```
resourcePath: /login
models:
  User:
    id: User
    properties:
      user_id:
        type: String
        description: Unique ID to represent the user
      first_name:
        type: String
        description: First name of the Uber user.
      last_name:
        type: String
        description: Last name of the Uber user.
      email:
        type: String
        description: Email address of the Uber user
      picture:
        type: String
        description: Image URL of the Uber user.
      promo_code:
        type: String
        description: Promo code of the Uber user.
```

The example on their github makes it look like this will work but I couldn't make it work.